# How to create uncompressed avi from a compressed video using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to create an uncompressed avi from a compressed video (.mpg). How do I do that using ffmpeg?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should however change the settings for your video:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mpg -y -f avi -b 1150 -s 320x240 -r 29.97 -g 12 -qmin 3 -qmax 13 -ab 224 -ar 44100 -ac 2 test.avi
```

[Source](http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-123414.html)